# Oracle SPLIT SUBPARTITION автоматизация

Tags: oracle, автоматизация, split, partition

Доброго времени суток всем!
Помогите решить такой вопрос. Создаю партиционированную таблицу в которой есть партиции и субпартиции(по датам, таблица разделена на годы, а годы разделены на кварталы) Создаю таким образом:

```
CREATE TABLE test_composite
(str_kv VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL,
d_1 date not null,
d_2 date not null) 

PARTITION BY RANGE(d_1)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE(d_2)
(
    PARTITION t_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01.01.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
      (
        SUBPARTITION t_20161 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01.04.2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')),
        SUBPARTITION t_20162 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01.07.2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')),
        SUBPARTITION t_20163 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01.10.2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')),
        SUBPARTITION t_20164 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
      ),
    PARTITION t_2017 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01.01.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
      (
        SUBPARTITION t_20171 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01.04.2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')),
        SUBPARTITION t_20172 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01.07.2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')),
        SUBPARTITION t_20173 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('01.10.2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')),
        SUBPARTITION t_20174 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
      ),
    PARTITION t_max VALUES LESS THAN (maxvalue)
);
```

Всё работает, далее встаёт вопрос, как можно оптимизировать процесс создания новых партиций(т.к. таблица будет расширяться)? Я знаю только как разбить существующую партицию(t_max) на две, но как одной операцией проделать так, чтобы воспроизвелась вся структура, вместе со всеми субпартициями? На данный момент при разделении основной партиции создаётся автоматическая субпартиция с системным именем, которая ни к селу ни к городу. Буду очень благодарен за помощь, и чем подробней будет помощь, тем лучше =)

Comment: Почитайте это, например https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-48168ACC-BA2A-4D2B-B693-F01DDAD82682.htm#VLDBG1192

Comment: Я это смотрел уже, это про изменение шаблона, у меня партиции создаются не на основе шаблона.

Comment: Тогда надо уточнить, что значит "оптимизировать процесс создания новых партиций (т.к. таблица будет расширяться)". Если новая секция верхнего уровня должна создаваться автоматически - то для этого может подойти ключевое слово INTERVAL.

Comment: Должна создаваться не только секция верхнего уровня(год), но также и 4 секции нижнего уровня(квартал), если честно я даже не знаю как просто в ручную это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter table TEST_COMPOSITE split partition  t_max at (TO_DATE('01.01.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
INTO (PARTITION t_2018, PARTITION t_max);

SELECT  subpartition_name
FROM user_tab_subpartitions
WHERE table_name = 'TEST_COMPOSITE' and partition_name='T_2018'
ORDER BY partition_name, subpartition_position; -- SYS_SUBP654

ALTER TABLE TEST_COMPOSITE
SPLIT SUBPARTITION SYS_SUBP654 AT (TO_DATE('01.10.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
INTO (SUBPARTITION T_20183, SUBPARTITION T_20184);
ALTER TABLE TEST_COMPOSITE
SPLIT SUBPARTITION T_20183 AT (TO_DATE('01.07.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
INTO (SUBPARTITION T_20182, SUBPARTITION T_20183);
ALTER TABLE TEST_COMPOSITE
SPLIT SUBPARTITION T_20182 AT (TO_DATE('01.04.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
INTO (SUBPARTITION T_20181, SUBPARTITION T_20182);
```